# Why does the Lisp reader return `(list 1 2 3)` instead of `(1 2 3)` when using reader macros?

Tags: common-lisp, evaluation, reader-macro

Recently, I tried to understand reader macros better. I have read an [article](https://lisper.in/reader-macros) about using reader macros to read in objects in JSON format.

With slightly adapted code from above article (it only reads (or is supposed to read) arrays `[1,2,3]` into lists `(1 2 3)`)

```cl
(defun read-next-object (separator delimiter &optional (input-stream *standard-input*))
  (flet ((peek-next-char ()
           (peek-char t input-stream t nil t))
         (discard-next-char ()
           (read-char input-stream t nil t)))
    (if (and delimiter (char= (peek-next-char) delimiter))
        (progn
          (discard-next-char)
          nil)
        (let* ((object (read input-stream t nil t))
               (next-char (peek-next-char)))
          (cond
            ((char= next-char separator) (discard-next-char))
            ((and delimiter (char= next-char delimiter)) nil)
            (t (error "Unexpected next char: ~S" next-char)))
          object))))

(defun read-separator (stream char)
  (declare (ignore stream))
  (error "Separator ~S shouldn't be read alone" char))

(defun read-delimiter (stream char)
  (declare (ignore stream))
  (error "Delimiter ~S shouldn't be read alone" char))

(defun read-left-bracket (stream char)
  (declare (ignore char))
  (let ((*readtable* (copy-readtable)))
    (set-macro-character #\, 'read-separator)
    (loop
       for object = (read-next-object #\, #\] stream)
       while object
       collect object into objects
       finally (return `(list ,@objects)))))
```

the intent is to call `read` on strings and have it produce Lisp lists.

With following test code I get:

```cl
(with-input-from-string (stream "[1,2,3]")
  (let ((*readtable* (copy-readtable)))
    (set-macro-character #\[ 'read-left-bracket)
    (set-macro-character #\] 'read-delimiter)
    (read stream)))
;; => (LIST 1 2 3)
```

I expected to get `(1 2 3)` instead.

Now, when I change the current readtable "permanently", i.e. call `set-macro-character` in the top-level, and type `[1,2,3]` at the prompt, I get indeed `(1 2 3)`.

Why, then, does

```cl
(with-input-from-string (stream "(1 2 3)")
  (read stream)))
;; => (1 2 3)
```

give the "expected" result? What am I missing? Is there some `eval` hidden, somewhere? (I'm aware of the quasi-quote above, but some in-between reasoning is missing...)

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

Using

```cl
(defun read-left-bracket (stream char)
  (declare (ignore char))
  (let ((*readtable* (copy-readtable)))
    (set-macro-character #\, 'read-separator)
    (loop
       for object = (read-next-object #\, #\] stream)
       while object
       collect object)))
```

I get what I expect. Entering `'[1,2,3]` at the REPL behaves like entering "real" lists.

Reading from strings also works as intended.

Comment: something like [nil,nil,nil] might be a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
(return `(list ,@objects))
```

in your code. Thus `[...]` is read as `(list ...)`.

Next if you use the REPL and evaluate

```
> [...]
```

Then it is as you were evaluating

```
> (list 1 2 3)
```

which returns `(1 2 3)`.

Comment: And if I wanted to get `(1 2 3)` directly? I could use `(return objects)`. Then I'd get what I want when reading from a string. But entering `[1,2,3]` at the REPL would fail.

Comment: @nosejose, you'd need to enter `'[...]` at the REPL. Alternative return a quoted list.

Comment: Thanks, due to the hint it dawned on me: I can just return the loop-collection, no need for the initial quoting.